# Spring Batch job Not ending

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have just started to use Spring batch and got stuck at this problem. My job never ends, its in an infinite loop. Below is the code:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        jobLauncher.run(flattenPersonJob(),new JobParameters());
        System.out.println("Done");

    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader itemReader() {
        return new PersonReader();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor itemProcessor() {
        return new PersonProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter itemWriter() {
        return new PersonWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step flattenPersonStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("flattenPersonStep").
                chunk(1).
                reader(itemReader()).
                processor(itemProcessor()).
                writer(itemWriter()).
                build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobListener jobListener() {
        return new JobListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job flattenPersonJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("flattenPersonJob").
                incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).
                listener(jobListener()).
                flow(flattenPersonStep()).
                end().
                build();
    }

}
```

This is my reader class

```
public class PersonReader implements ItemReader<List<Person>> {

    @Override
    public List<Person> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        System.out.println("This is the reader");
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(new Person("","",""));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return personList;
    }
}
```

This is my writer class

```
public class PersonWriter implements ItemWriter<List<String>> {
@Override
public void write(List<? extends List<String>> items) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("This is the writer");
    //Thread.sleep(5000);
    items.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

}

This is my processor class

```
public class PersonProcessor implements ItemProcessor<List<Person>, List<String>> {
@Override
public List<String> process(List<Person> item) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("This is the processor");
    //Thread.sleep(5000);
    return item.stream().map(n -> n.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

Is there any configuration that I am missing here ??
Or is there something wrong with my code ?

I have googled for some time now, but couldnot find anything constructive.

Any help here is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Amar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your reader never returns null.  The contract for the `ItemReader` within Spring Batch is to read until the reader returns null (indicating that the input has been exhausted).  Since you never return null from your `ItemReader`...your job will read for ever.